# Why if I place the zero of the lead compensator at lower frequencies, do I obtain a resonance peak?

Tags: frequency-response, control-systems, bode

I am studying control systems, and I am studying the lead and lag compensator. I have seen than if I use a lead compensator for the closed loop transfer function,

$T(s)=\frac{s+2}{(s+1)(s+8)},$

with the designed lead compensator,

$lead(s) = \frac{3s+1}{0.1s+1}$

and I use it as a pre-compensator, so that the lead compensator is outside the loop,

$lead(s)\cdot T(s),$

and plot the frequency response, I see that I have a frequency response in which there is a resonance peak, which increases as I decrease the frequency at which the zero is present.

[image]

In this case, the red line is a lead compensator defined as,

$\frac{3s+1}{0.1s+1},$

and the green line is the system in which I have used the following compensator,

$\frac{6s+1}{0.1s+1}.$

Can somebody explain to me why?

Comment: Hint : Plot the frequency of both compensators.

Which one has the highest gain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first compensator $\frac{3s+1}{0.1s + 1}$ has a high-frequency gain of 30.

The second compensator $\frac{6s+1}{0.1s + 1}$ has a high-frequency gain of 60.

The difference is 6.02 dB, it looks pretty close to the difference between the green and red line.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I would like to ask if there is a reason of why this happen, or it is just a computational issue?

Comment: Do you know how to compute a transfer function gain at infinite frequency?

It's basically L'Hospital rule